# Collecting the output of an external command using OCaml

Tags: unix, ocaml

What is the right way to call an external command and collect its output in OCaml?

In Python, I can do something like this:

```
os.popen('cmd').read()
```

How I can get all of an external program's output in OCaml? Or, better, OCaml with Lwt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You want [Unix.open_process_in](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALopen_process_in), which is described on page 388 of the OCaml system manual, version 3.10.

Answer (score 7):

For Lwt,

> val pread : ?env:string array -> command -> string Lwt.t

seems to be a good contender. Documentation here: http://ocsigen.org/docu/1.3.0/Lwt_process.html

Answer (score 4):

```
let process_output_to_list2 = fun command -> 
  let chan = Unix.open_process_in command in
  let res = ref ([] : string list) in
  let rec process_otl_aux () =  
    let e = input_line chan in
    res := e::!res;
    process_otl_aux() in
  try process_otl_aux ()
  with End_of_file ->
    let stat = Unix.close_process_in chan in (List.rev !res,stat)
let cmd_to_list command =
  let (l,_) = process_output_to_list2 command in l
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the third party library [Rashell](https://github.com/michipili/rashell) which uses Lwt to define some high-level primitives to read output from processes.  These primitives, defined in the module [Rashell_Command](https://github.com/michipili/rashell/blob/master/src/rashell_Command.mli), are:

- `exec_utility` to read the output of a process as a string;
- `exec_test` to only read the exit status of a process;
- `exec_query` to read the output of a process line by line as a `string Lwt_stream.t`
- `exec_filter` to use an external program as a `string Lwt_stream.t -> string Lwt_stream.t` transformation.

The `command` function is used to create command contexts on which the previous primitives can be applied, it has the signature:

```
val command : ?workdir:string -> ?env:string array -> string * (string array) -> t
(** [command (program, argv)] prepare a command description with the
    given [program] and argument vector [argv]. *)
```

So for instance

```
Rashell_Command.(exec_utility ~chomp:true (command("", [| "uname" |])))
```

is a `string Lwt.t` which returns the “chomped” string (new line removed) of the “uname” command. As a second example

```
Rashell_Command.(exec_query (command("", [| "find"; "/home/user"; "-type"; "f"; "-name"; "*.orig" |])))
```

is a `string Lwt_stream.t` whose elements are the paths of the file found by the command

```
find /home/user -type f -name '*.orig'
```

The Rashell library defines also interfaces to some commonly used commands, and a nice interface to the `find` command is defined in `Rashell_Posix` – which by the way guarantees POSIX portability.

Comment: Seems like rashell might be dead these days ? That's unfortunate, it looked great

Comment: @Ulrar Well I do not know what you mean by dead but for me it currently fills it’s job. What are you missing there? You are welcome to open tickets! :)

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to compile anymore, looks like it references lwt.ppx which as I understand it doesn't exist anymore, replaced by lwt_ppx. Ot is the version in opam just very old ?

Comment: @Ulrar Well I did not follow the recent development of OCaml and Lwt but maybe it I is now time to catch up. :) if you open a ticket on GitHub you will get some news as it’s is fixed.

Comment: Sure, just did. There was already one, but the issue wasn't really the same so I made a new issue. I expect solving the dependency issue might reveal the other issue from 2017 though. Thanks !

Comment: Do you know when you'll get a chance to take a look at it ? Just to know if I wait or if I go with something else

Comment: I will try to have a look at this on the weekend, it should not be that much work.

Answer (score 0):

Install batteries and then depend on it as a library, then:

```ml
BatUnix.run_and_read 'cmd'
```

Its interface is:

```ml
val BatUnix.run_and_read string -> BatUnix.process_status * string
```