# Function returns String result of external command

Tags: ocaml

According to this post, there is a code that returns list string * Unix.processStatus.

[Collecting the output of an external command using OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214970/collecting-the-output-of-an-external-command-using-ocaml)

But how do you rewrite this code to return a String only? 
For example when I run

echo 'test' | base64

I just want to get the encoded string only as a result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the process status tells you whether the command worked correctly. So you're saying you don't care if it works, you just want the answer.

There is a built-in OCaml function named `fst` that returns the first part of a pair and throws away the second part. You can use it to get just the `string` from `string * Unix.processStatus`.

Comment: Thanks you, fst function and String.concat solved the problem.

Comment: (If you're just using `String.concat` to concatenate two strings, you might also want to look at the operator `^`. It's simpler for just two strings.)

Comment: Thank you, could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729842/socket-onread-onready-onclose-event-handler-function-in-ocaml as well?