# Socket onread, onready, onclose event handler function in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am developing a protocol using TCP/IP socket in Ocaml and I am interested implementing the event driven approach. Basically, I want to make event handling functions that invokes whenever socket receives a new data or closed or opened.

Is it possible to do in Ocaml without implementing it manually using multiple threads?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Make a loop and use [`Unix.select`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALselect) to wait for events on your fds. You will have to set your sockets to non-blocking mode with [`Unix.set_nonblock`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALset_nonblock) so that your reads and writes don't block and you can get back to your select if there's no data to read/write (because even if `select` returns you fds that are readable/writable it doesn't mean that a read/write on them wouldn't block).

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me an example of implementing this?

Comment: Google says http://www.mega-nerd.com/erikd/Blog/CodeHacking/Ocaml/ocaml_select.html