# Ocaml function that returns "" or null when there is nothing to read from socket

Tags: sockets, ocaml

I am using `input_line` function to read new data from client socket but the function stops the thread when there is nothing left to read from stream. My goal is to build a function that returns an empty string (i.e. "") when there is nothing to left to read, instead of stopping the thread.

How would you build this function using `input_line` or other method?

Answer (score 3):

`input_line` raises the exception `End_of_file` when the end of file is reached. Just catch the exception and return the empty string:

```
try input_line ic with End_of_file -> ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but input_line still blocks and does not throw "" when there are nothing to read.

Comment: I misunderstood you because you said "when there is *nothing left* to read from the stream". So I thought when the socket is closed. Of course an input will block until there's more data. If you want non blocking semantics you'll have to look into what gasche suggests especially [Unix.set_nonblock](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALset_nonblock). See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729842/socket-onread-onready-onclose-event-handler-function-in-ocaml/16733064) question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`input` function](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALinput), which is lower-level than `input_line` and will not block but instead report that it could read less characters than what you asked for.

If you want to have lower-level control on your input/output (blocking reads, polling, etc.), you should maybe rather use the [Unix](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) module that can manipulate the underlying file descriptors. It gives you access in particular to the [Unix.select function](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALselect) to wait on a set of inputs, or low-level [Unix.read](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALread) and [Unix.write](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALwrite) input-output functions.

Finally, you may be interested in the online book [Unix System Programming in OCaml](http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/) that has examples of these kind of programs.

Comment: There is nothing in the link you cited that states it won't block. *Any* TCP read can read less bytes than you asked for: this is the nature of TCP.

Answer (score 2):

> the function stops the thread when there is nothing left to read from stream

No it doesn't. It *blocks* the thread *while* there is no data available to be read. The sender may be about to send more data in a minute's time, or an hour, or a day.

The condition 'nothing left to read from the stream' means that the peer has closed the connection, in which case you won't get blocking, you will get some kind of end-of-stream indication.

> My goal is to build a function that returns an empty string (i.e. "") when there is nothing to left to read, instead of stopping the thread.

Then you need to use non-blocking mode, or `MSG_PEEK` if it's available via your API.