# In OCaml, how to get stdout string from subprocess?

Tags: subprocess, ocaml, stdout

I'm working with OCaml and need to start a new process and communicate with it.

1. If the subprocess terminated once it's called and produced some output, then how to retrieve the strings in it's stdout?
2. What if the subprocess never terminates? That is, everytime given a string to stdin, it will produce a result to stdout, how to fetch the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collecting the output of an external command using OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214970/collecting-the-output-of-an-external-command-using-ocaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Unix.open_process_in` function. It will spawn a process and return an input channel, that will allow you to read data from the process.

If you want to wait for the process to terminate, you can just read all the data (i.e., wait until the process pipe returns EOF), and then close the channel, e.g.,

```
(* [run cmd] runs a shell command, waits until it terminates, and  
   returns a list of strings that the process outputed *)
let run cmd =
  let inp = Unix.open_process_in cmd in
  let r = In_channel.input_lines inp in
  In_channel.close inp; r
```

Working with non-terminating process is even easier.

You may also find interesting lwt library that has a very descent interface to multiprocessing. And async library is another asynchronous library that provide an excellent interface to multiprocessing. Although, this libraries are great, they are little bit advance, for simple cases standard `Unix` module is enough.

Comment: Is this using the Jane Street "Core" library? i.e.`Stdio.In_channel.input_lines`  
https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/stdio/Stdio/In_channel/index.html#val-input_lines ?

Comment: Yes, the stdio library from the core suite. But the latest version of OCaml already has this module in its standard library.

Comment: closest I could find is `input_line` in Pervasives, and then I guess have to write your own func to repeat that until they're all read

Comment: Indeed, the stdio module will be introduced only in the next version of OCaml (which is currently in beta). So unless you have specific reasons not to install stdio with `opam search stdio` (don't hesitate to ask for help if you have trouble installing or using it), you can easily write your own function that inputs all lines from a file, here is the example https://stackoverflow.com/a/23456034/2625442

Comment: ah nice, is that for 5.0 or a future 4.xx release?

Comment: for 4.14 and above (5.x including)